# How to convert epoch time to ISO 8601 using moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs, package

I have epoch time in array `"task[i]["due_on"]=1533541797"` which I am trying to convert to ISO 8601 using 'moment'. I have also tried in different ways but it always shows a different error.

---

```
var moment = require('moment'); 
var dueon_date = moment(task[i]["due_on"]).format(); 
console.log("date",dueon_date);
```

### console logs output - **Invalid date**

Comment: JavaScript uses milliseconds, so you need to start by multiplying your epoch timestamp (which is in seconds) by 1,000, before you feed it to any JS date functionality …

Comment: @CBroe removed pointless comment.

Comment: Try using an output format inside the format.

Comment: moment(1533541797).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : 
'1970-01-18'

Comment: Try this `moment(1533541797*1000).toISOString()`

Comment: @HassanImam Thank you for the reply, it's working but there are also null values and it always shows "1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"  this time how will you handle this?

Comment: Add condition for null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [specify the input format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```js
var dueon_date = moment("1533541797", "X").format();
console.log(dueon_date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```